# Bison looking forwardard in code

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I'm writing a compiler using Bison which will translate a simple programing language to instructions for some register machine with only one accumulator. I want to save some time loading and saving values. My Bison code looks like this:

```
ID ASSIGN expression { 
                        if(id_exists($1))
                        {
                            addCode("STORE ", getAdress($1));
                        } 
                        else
                            YYERROR;
                     }
```

For example, given the input below:

```
a ASSIGN 1000;
b ASSSIGN a * 2;
b ASSIGN  b / 2;
```

The output of my compiler would look like this:

```
(Here A is assigned 1000)
STORE a_adress;
SHL
STORE b_adress
SHR
STORE b_Adress
```

Well, it's obvious that the middle `STORE` is not needed, but how could I know that in the next operation I would have `b` as one of the operands so I could avoid this `STORE` operation?

Comment: This isn't really a good task for bison. You will want to do the analysis and optimization in a second pass over the generated code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization might give you some ideas.

Comment: is it possible using only bison ?

Comment: What does it mean to "only use bison"? Most of the code in your bison file is in C; obviously, you can solve this problem in C, so you could embed the solution in bison. That would not be a natural use of bison, because bison is a tool for parsing, not for analysing parses, generating code, or optimizing it, but I'm certain you could pervert a bison description sufficiently to be able to claim that you did peephole optimization "in bison". But in no way will bison help you. I'll stand by my original formulation: "This isn't a good task for bison."